# Imageview inside relative layout does not stretch full view

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

If i inflate this item and show it in my listview, the imageview does not fill the parent i.e it just stretch till the width but it won't expand till the view height.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp">

     <ImageView
         android:layout_width="10dp"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
         android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
         android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
         android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
         android:id="@+id/ID_task_item_priority"
         android:src="@color/abs__background_holo_dark"/>

    <TextView 
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="Your title"
         android:id="@+id/ID_task_item_title"
         android:singleLine="true"
         android:ellipsize="end"
         android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ID_task_item_priority"
         android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
         android:textSize="25sp"
        />

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ID_task_item_notes"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ID_task_item_title"
        android:maxLines="3"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:text="Your note"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ID_task_item_priority"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        />

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/id_due_date"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ID_task_item_notes"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="10-2-2014"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        />

         <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/ID_task_item_is_completed_checkbox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/ID_task_item_title"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ID_task_item_title"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp" /> 

</RelativeLayout>
```

item image [image]

Comment: Have you tried adding android:scaleType="fitXY"?

Comment: In relative layout imageview?

Comment: Yes in the imageview xml declaration

Comment: `<ImageView
         android:layout_width="10dp"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
         android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
         android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
         android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
         android:scaleType="fitXY"
         android:id="@+id/ID_task_item_priority"
         android:src="@color/abs__background_holo_dark"/>` tried like this, no luck :(. imageview is not at all stretching to view height.

Comment: If i hardcode the height, it stretches but why not if i give fill_parent?

Comment: Try using android:background instead of android:src

Comment: In your program, do you set any image to that ImageView? If yes then it will try to maintain its aspect ratio. If you fill only color in xml it will stretch.

Comment: oh, ok i got it, instead of image, i need to specify color right, ill try one min

Comment: ` <ImageView
         android:layout_width="10dp"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
         android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
         android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
         android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
         android:id="@+id/ID_task_item_priority"
         android:scaleType="fitXY"
         android:src="#000000"/>.` No luck :(... i tried.

Answer (score 2):

you set image layout parameter run-time as per device configuration

Use this code to set image-view width and height same as screen parameter

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    int width = metrics.widthPixels;
    int height = metrics.heightPixels;
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.rl_main);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lparams= new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width,height);

    ImageView iv= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    relativeLayout.removeView(iv);
    relativeLayout.addView(iv,lparams);
```

This may help you

Comment: Hi, why not the static code will not work here, what is the issue?

Comment: because different devices have different screen resolution and any image have not same one then it not fit our parent in relative layout

Comment: if i inflate the view on listview then only problem appears, but simply if i run this code in a view, it works ok

Comment: i want to implement by static code, my problem is. if i inflate the above layout and provide to listview. the image i.e a black color strip does not fill from top to bottom. It just stay at extreme left corner it look only 10dp thin in wide. thats all.

Comment: that is because you set your parameter android:layout_width=10dp of your imageview

Comment: i need need a strip of width 10dp and height should be full view.